# Serverless-offline does not recognize graphql handler as a function

Tags: typescript, webpack, apollo-server, serverless-offline

I'm trying to convert my serverless nodejs graphql api to use typescript but serverless throws an error stating that the graphql handler is not a function.

Error message:

```
Error: Serverless-offline: handler for 'hello' is not a function
    at Object.createHandler (/home/savnik/serverless-webpack-typescript-apollo/node_modules/serverless-offline/src/functionHelper.js:221:11)
    at handler (/home/savnik/serverless-webpack-typescript-apollo/node_modules/serverless-offline/src/ApiGateway.js:485:40)
    at module.exports.internals.Manager.execute (/home/savnik/serverless-webpack-typescript-apollo/node_modules/@hapi/hapi/lib/toolkit.js:41:33)
    at Object.internals.handler (/home/savnik/serverless-webpack-typescript-apollo/node_modules/@hapi/hapi/lib/handler.js:46:48)
    at exports.execute (/home/savnik/serverless-webpack-typescript-apollo/node_modules/@hapi/hapi/lib/handler.js:31:36)
    at Request._lifecycle (/home/savnik/serverless-webpack-typescript-apollo/node_modules/@hapi/hapi/lib/request.js:312:68)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at Request._execute (/home/savnik/serverless-webpack-typescript-apollo/node_modules/@hapi/hapi/lib/request.js:221:9)
```

The objective is to create an apollo graphql api which uses typescript and can be used offline for development purpose.

I have reproduced the issue here:
https://github.com/savnik/serverless-webpack-typescript-apollo

Any thoughts on what is the root cause for this issue?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this? I'm having the same issue...

Comment: Yes the problem is a stated in the comment of pd76 a issue with `exports.graphqlHandler = server.createHandler();`

Comment: Oh, OK.. for me that wasn't the issue. I was exporting an async function call, so the exported thing was not a function but a promise instead. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are still using 'export' syntax for a js module.

In src/handler.ts, change the last line from `exports.graphqlHandler = server.createHandler()` to `export const graphqlHandler = server.createHandler()`